# Username password hash setting

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I tried to set the UserName as my custom Firstname+ Lastname properties. It sets it ok. But when I try to log in fails. Is this because the password is hashed using the email as salt? any way I can override this to still use the email as hash at login time but use the username as username?

I am using Identity 2.0.0 beta1

Resolved.
I had left a space for aesthetic purposes between the firstname and lastname fields. removing this space has resolved the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The salt for ASP.NET Identity's password hashing is generated automatically. In essence, the password hashing is the same as this description:

http://brockallen.com/2012/10/19/password-management-made-easy-in-asp-net-with-the-crypto-api/